# How to Enable port forwarding on azure vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

Hi I have a azure vm on which I want to configure port forwarding so that I can redirect traffic to 1100 port, I have created a public loadbalancer and in NAT rule I have configured the ports, but seems that I cant RDP onto the VM using my port 1100, can anyone suggest me some documents where I can get this thing done?

Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to RDP your Azure VM through the front port 1100 of Load Balancer.

So you need to add your VM into the Backend pools of Load Balancer, and then create NAT rule to forward the traffic to your VM through port 1100 exposed to the internet.

The NAT rule setting panel will like this:
[image]

You can select your VM at which I frame up with the red pen if you added it to the Load Balancer backend pools. And you can set **port** as 1100 and **target port** as 3389 which RDP really used. When it's OK. You can connect your Azure VM through port 1100.

You can get more details with the document [Create inbound NAT rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal#create-inbound-nat-rules).

Comment: Hi Charles thanks for you response, can you tell us what rules we need to add into the network security group in order to successfully RDP using the public port?

Comment: You can add the rule with allowing the port 3389. After the traffic come through the Load Balancer, it will go through the NSG with the target port 3389. So you need to allow the port 3389.

Comment: But allowing the port 3389 will attract external traffic we dont need that.

Comment: The port 3389 will not be exposed to the Internet. You use Load Balancer with a front port 1100 and you will RDP the VM with port 1100 from the internet. From the internet, all people can just see port 1100 for RDP.

Comment: After adding the port 3389 and my default port 1100, I can access the machine using my loadbalancer IP as well as machine Ip, just the case I can access my machine using 1100 and 3389 both ports, thats not what I wanted

Comment: You need to remove the public IP associated with the VM network interface. Just keep the way to RDP your VM from the Load Balancer.

Comment: So I was having diffenet IPs for loadbalancer and for VMs guess I was RDP using the VM's ips using 3389 and was getting successful login attempt, can you tell me what kind of nsg rules should be set up so that we can block the vm's publicip

Comment: As I know you cannot do this. You can use RDP your VM through Load Balancer or the VM public IP, but when your traffic comes in, it just has one target -- your VM, ignore the way your traffic comes. So if you want to RDP your VM and not expose port 3389 to the internet. You just can use Load Balancer and remove the public IP from your VM network interface. You cannot block the port 3389 in NSG, if you do so, no one can RDP your VM.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful to you!