# Azure VM Port forwarding to localhost port

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM, and a web application listening internally on port 32001. The VM is publicly accessible on a static IP address. I'm trying to route all traffic the VM receives on port 443 to its localhost port 32001. I am try to set it up in this screen, and my first idea was to edit the HTTPS rule. But no matter what I try, I can't seem to get a connection to my webapp. What am I supposed to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using just VM. What you actually need is a Load Balancer in front of your Azure VM which takes care on port forwarding. An example you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal) and [here](https://rasmusg.net/2017/11/20/part-2-of-2-port-forwarding-in-azure/). But in short, what you need to do is:

- expose 32001 on your VM
- create Load Balancer
- add VM to backend pool in Load Balancer
- configure port forwarding on this balancer

In inbound and outband rules you can configure what traffic is allowed, but you can't configure there port forwarding.

You can also check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094655/how-to-enable-port-forwarding-on-azure-vm)